# ¿Cómo puedo iterar en Jade con distintos contenidos?

Tags: html, jade

El siguiente código en Jade me crea 3 divs similares, con distintos h1(HTML, CSS, Javascript).
Lo que no puedo conseguir es agregarle contenido distinto para cada h2 y cada p. ¿Alguna idea? gracias.

```
.Blog
  each title in ['HTML', 'CSS', 'Javascript']
    include ../article/template.jade
```

El article/template.jade sería:

```
.Article
  h1=title
  h2
  p
```

Para hacer este código me he basado en las referencias de [iteración en el sitio de jade](http://jade-lang.com/reference/iteration/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para lo que estas haciendo te recomiendo que uses un `mixin` en lugar de un `include`. Ambos funcionan de manera similar pero el [mixin](http://jade-lang.com/reference/mixins) es un bloque reutilizable y te permite pasar variables al bloque de html que intentas crear por lo que su funcionamiento será obvio y funciona a la perfección con las variables de los iteradores.

```
mixin article(art)
    .Article
        h1=art.title
        h2=art.subtitle
        p=art.content

.Blog
    each art in [{title: 'HTML', subtitle: 'Core', content: 'Lorem ipsum'}]
        +article(art)
```

Los datos sobre los que iteras deben ser un arreglo de objetos en lugar de un arreglo de `string` para que puedas tener acceso en el ciclo al contenido adicional que que intentas agregar.

Comment: Gracias @devconcept!! me ha funcionado. Al final el código del ejemplo quedaría así:
    .Blog
 each art in [{title: 'HTML', subtitle: 'Core', content: 'Lorem ipsum'},{title: 'CSS', subtitle: 'CoreCSS', content: 'LoremCSS'},{title: 'Javascript', subtitle: 'CoreJS', content: 'LoremJS'}]
     +article(art)    . En tu código después de 'Core' va una "," en vez de ":"  . Intenté editarlo pero no me permitieron por no llegar a los 6 caracteres. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda.